# Getting a compilation error for not providing a default constructor. Is it really needed here?

Tags: c++

Here's the code:

```
Order received_order = Order(order_type, price, qty, id, curr_time);
std::map<std::string, OrderBook> buy_side_symbols;

auto have_symbol = buy_side_symbols.find(symbol);

if (have_symbol == buy_side_symbols.end())
    buy_side_symbols.emplace(symbol, OrderBook(symbol));

buy_side_symbols[symbol].addOrder(received_order);
```

In the last line of code, which calls the `addOrder()` method of class `OrderBook`, it's giving a compilation error for not having a default constructor in class `OrderBook`. But, as far as I know, a default object need not be constructed as I'm already constructing one in case the key is not found in the map.

So, what's the reason for this error? What am I missing here?

Edit 1: I've added the OrderBook class and addOrder method below.

Edit 2: I've removed the Edit 1 as I've got the answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: It would be relevant to share the `addOrder` method and the constructors available in `OrderBook`.

Comment: A `map` always needs a default constructor in case you give it a key that doesn't exist in `operator[]`, it will create a default object.

Comment: Not the question, but: if the symbol is present, `have_symbol` holds an iterator that points at it. If the symbol is not present, `emplace` returns an iterator that points at the newly-created symbol. Either way, you've got an iterator that points where you need to be, so there's no need to search again with `buy_side_symbols[symbol]`.

Comment: _Here's the code_ No it isn't, here is a **minute fraction** of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) requires the `mapped_type` to be [*DefaultConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible).  If you request a key that does not exist, the operator must be able to default-construct a new object.

In your case, you are asking the operator for a key that always exists, but the compiler doesn't know that.  The path that handles missing keys still needs to be valid code, even if it is never invoked.

You can work around this issue by simply not using `operator[]` at all.  You can instead use the `iterator` that both `map::find()` and `map::emplace()` return to you.  Which you should do anyway, as it avoids having to perform a 2nd lookup of the symbol you already found/added.

Try this:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, OrderBook> buy_side_symbols;

auto symbol_iter = buy_side_symbols.find(symbol);

if (symbol_iter == buy_side_symbols.end())
    symbol_iter = buy_side_symbols.emplace(symbol, symbol).first;

symbol_iter->second.addOrder(received_order);
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/8XcU54)

Comment: Thanks I see so it's compiler just making sure that a default constructor is available even if the key already exists. Also thanks for the iterator method I didn't knew I could do it like this also.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the description of [`map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) you'll see that it requires `mapped_type` to be [DefaultConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultConstructible).  That's because if the key doesn't exist in the map, it will create an entry for it and fill it with a default constructed object.  It doesn't matter if you never use `operator[]`, the class must compile it anyway.

Comment: Can explain the line "It doesn't matter if you never use operator[], the class must compile it anyway" a bit more. Cause I'm still confused, I understand that a default constructor would be needed in case the key is not present in the map but such a case would never arise as I'm already using emplace to insert the key in case it's not there.

Comment: @GameCode At the point where you invoke `operator[]`, the compiler does not know that it does not need to insert the element anymore. It has to compile the code that inserts it anyway.

Comment: I see, I was kinda thinking the same thing when I got the error. Thanks for the help.